# How to have a gradient background on a page that covers the entire page without the "window-blind effect"?

Tags: background, gradient, background-color, css

I want my page to have a gradient color, going from dark on the left age to bright in the middle, and back to dark at the right edge. I've seen some examples for creating gradients, but I don't know see where in the CSS the size of the pattern is being set, and the pattern is repeating too quickly for my taste.

As an example, here's some CSS:

```
html {
   background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#2F2727), to(#1a82f7));
   background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7); 
   background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);
   background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);
   background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);
}
```

...that I found here: http://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/

And here's a jsfiddle you can run that has that:

http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/VLXbu/

It can't be a fixed size, because of the variance is screen sizes, between phones and desktops, in particular. Is there a way to accomplish this using %s of screen width?

Comment: set the height of the `html` element to 100%

Comment: Exactly. Explanation: the html is only as high as its content, namely the 100px high section. @onetrickpony, why don't you post this as an answer?

Comment: @ClayShannonand you should really end with the generic (not prefixed) `linear-gradient`. That way it will remain up-to-date longer.

Comment: Updated it with your comments. http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/VLXbu/2/
I will mark as answer if you add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
html {
background: #2f2727; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2f2727 0%, #1a82f7 49%, #1a82f7 49%, #2f2727 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#2f2727), color-stop(49%,#1a82f7), color-stop(49%,#1a82f7), color-stop(100%,#2f2727)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2f2727 0%,#1a82f7 49%,#1a82f7 49%,#2f2727 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #2f2727 0%,#1a82f7 49%,#1a82f7 49%,#2f2727 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #2f2727 0%,#1a82f7 49%,#1a82f7 49%,#2f2727 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #2f2727 0%,#1a82f7 49%,#1a82f7 49%,#2f2727 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2f2727', endColorstr='#2f2727',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
min-height: 100%; height: auto !important; height: 100%;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pepean/hSjdg/2/